# How to translate other languages to English in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-translate

I am having an excel file where the "value" column contains different language statements. I want to translate the entire value column into English.

[image]

For testing purpose I'm using the below code, but it's throwing some exception

```
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator
exl_file = 'ipfile1.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(exl_file)
print(df)

translator = Translator()
df1 = df['value'].apply(translator.translate, src='es', dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
print(df1)
```

Can you please guide how to apply translator on each rows to convert into English?

Comment: Next time you should include the exception from your code. This question was simple enough, but tracebacks are useful for debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `.apply` the translator to the `value` column like this:

```py
df['translated_value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='en').text)
```

Comment: I was getting some exception which is resolved by installing google_trans_new and few changes in the code. like:  from google_trans_new import google_translator  
translator = google_translator()                                                                                       df['translated_value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, lang_tgt='en'))

Comment: Google translate was not working for me. But 'pinyin' worked for me. df['translated_value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: pinyin.get(x, format="strip", delimiter=" "))

Answer (score 3):

Google Translate has limits on volume translated. [EasyNMT](https://github.com/UKPLab/EasyNMT) is a scalable solution.

```
from easynmt import EasyNMT
model = EasyNMT("opus-mt")

df["value_en"] = df.apply(lambda row: model.translate(row["value"], target_lang="en"), axis=1)
```