# How to Prepare a Dataset with Multilingual Text

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, text-classification

I am preparing a dataset for text classification in Jupyter Notebook.

**However, one of the column have text sentences which contains words in both Indonesian and English language.**
`Example: 'ETUDE READY NO. 4 DAN 5\n\nTulis di keterangan'`

*Anybody can advise how I should pre-process this text column?*

Comment: For simple text classification you probably don't need to do anything about it. Fyi this is called [code switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching). I wouldn't try to translate it if I were you, unless you have a specific reason to.

Answer (score 0):

There n number of ways you can translates data frames. As a developer I recommend to do some basic internet research. Here I'm dropping some links..

> Link1:
> https://pretagteam.com/question/translate-dataframe-python-to-english-and-save-the-result-into-a-cvs-file
>
> Link2: [How to translate other languages to English in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67303463/15358800)
>
> Link3: [Python pandas: Create a new column with values in English by converting values stored in a different column in Chinese traditional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50796361/15358800)